# What exactly is pairwise orthogonal?

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal

Suppose there exists a basis $$B = \left \{  v_{1},...,v_{n}\right \}$$ and basis $$B' = \left \{  v_{1}',...,v_{n}'\right \}$$

Then, if $$\left \langle B,B' \right \rangle=0$$ 
then B and B' are orthogonal to each other.

What about pairwise orthogonality?

Comment: I don't understand your  ‘condition’. $\langle B,B'\rangle$ is a number, not a condition.

Comment: How do you define $\left \langle B,B' \right \rangle$ for two sets of vectors? Pairwise orthogonal would be e.g. $\left \langle v_i,v_k' \right \rangle=0$, but this can not be true for all $i,k$ because each $v_i=\sum a_{i,k}v'_k.$

Comment: @gammatester Indeed, I think my confusion stems from misunderstanding the ideas.

Comment: How do you define $\langle B, B' \rangle$ ? For example, if $B=\{[1,0], [0,1]\}$ and $B' = \{[2,3], [3,2]\}$, then how do you calculate $\langle B, B'\rangle$?

Comment: How can two bases be orthogonal to each other? I can't think of any interpretation that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One usually uses "pairwise" when one has a set of more than two different objects. For instance, the vectors $B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4$ are pairwise orthogonal if for any $i \neq j$, we have $\langle B_i, B_j\rangle = 0$, i.e. any *pair* of vectors from your set is an orthogonal pair. Is that what you're looking for?

**Edit** I misread the question, thinking $B, B'$ were the *vectors*, not bases of vector spaces. In this case I would interpret the sentence "$B$ and $B'$ are pairwise orthogonal" as the following:
$$
\text{For any } i, j\text{ we have } \langle v_i, v'_j\rangle = 0
$$

Comment: So basically all that means is that given a basis vector, if the indices of the elements in the basis vector are different, then the dot product of 2 elements results to 0? And if the indices are the same, the dot product of the 2 elements equals 1?

Comment: Generally there is no natural ordering, so _the same index_ is not well defined.

Comment: After your edit my comment to the question applies, the inner products can not all be zero because otherwise $B$ and $B'$ could not be bases.

Comment: @gammatester They could be bases for two different (and apparently orthogonal) subspaces of a bigger space.

Comment: That would mean, that they are **not** bases of the complete space (and I guess the same number $n$ means we are talking about $n$-dimensional spaces, otherwise one base count should be say $m$)

Comment: @gammatester That's exactly what it would mean (and I agree with you that if they _are_ indeed bases of the full space, then there is no way they are pairwise disjoint the way I wrote in my edit above). Any linearly independent set of vectors is a basis for the space it spans, whether they live in some bigger, outer vector space or not. That's how I see it anyway.